# about xml datatype

Tags: types, xsd

I'm using xml for my application. And I used xml schema. In that schema i used `int` datatype for numeric field. But i don't know the exact max range of `int` datatype. Means how big value it can hold for int datatype?

Can anyone knows this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [XML Schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#integer):

> The ·value space· of **integer** is the infinite set {...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...}.

So there are no specified limits on the size. However, for the base type [decimal](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal):

> All ·minimally conforming· processors ·must· support decimal numbers with a minimum of 18 decimal digits (i.e., with a ·totalDigits· of 18). However, ·minimally conforming· processors ·may· set an application-defined limit on the maximum number of decimal digits they are prepared to support, in which case that application-defined maximum number ·must· be clearly documented.

So implementation defined limits are allowed as long as they're specified and support at least 18 digits. To be safe, I'd probably stick with 32bit integers and test anything larger than that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as XML itself goes, as big as you need.
As far as whatever language you parse it with, well, it depends on language and parser but it's likely to be a 32bit signed integer.